# Session not writing fast enough to prevent duplicate form submissions on backend. (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, forms, session

I have a `createOrder` request that is currently a little slow (about 3 - 4 seconds). I am attempting to prevent a duplicate form submission using the CSRF token, or a custom token.

For this instance, I am using valet with a file driver... so this may well be the issue but I am yet to push this code into a production server as it is not working as intended.

It works like this:

- The token is added to the session and to the submit form in a hidden `"custom_token"` field.
- The form is submitted and either within the middleware or the controller itself we do a quick comparison.

```
if(! hash_equals($request->session()->get('custom_token'), $request->custom_token)){
    flash()->error('Order placed twice');
    return redirect('/checkout/thank-you');
}

$request->session()->put('custom_token', Str::random(40));
```

- If they do not match we do a quick redirect (Flash message only there for debugging currently).

The above works if I remove the main create orde call from the controller (i.e. the slow bit) but with this included the hash_equals always returns true.

So my questions are:

1. Is this likely to be caused by the slow updating of a session file driver?
2. Surely if this is the case, even in a production environment there is still some risk of this happening.
3. Is there a better way I can prevent duplicate form submission on the backend?

Comment: Why the `!` in `if(! hash_equals`?

Comment: If hashes do not equal, throw the error?

Comment: Ok, now that code is making sense, but, it is not necessary that inequality means request placed twice.  Anyone could tweak the custom_token with inspect element.

Comment: I am assuming once the CSRF token is used, it can't be played again and Laravel would blacklist it itself. But I hope you have that VerifyCsrfToken middleware enabled on your routes.

Comment: If `hash_equals` is true once, the next thing we do is re-write the `custom_token` with a new one. This is less about someone hacking the system, more just to be sure that a normal user cannot ever submit twice if clicking the submit button in quick submission, or pressing back on the browser and resubmitting that way.

Comment: Yes we have CSRF. I have tried the same idea with CSRF but I get the same issues. Like I say, I think the session is not writing fast enough so the next form submission is still getting the old session value.

Comment: Does this check happen before processing the input or after processing the input? I mean is this a BeforeMiddleware or AfterMiddleware? Also, it shouldn't be about fast or slow writing of sessions as PHP code is synchronous, meaning, next command is executed only after previous command completes.

Comment: I have tried it in middleware and also in the first section of the controller. Yes php is synchronous within the script but it is possible to initiate 2 requests at once. By the time the second request goes to read the session it has not yet had time to update.

Answer (score 1):

A few things, first I would sort out why your createOrder is taking so long, 3 to 4 seconds is a long time. Use a Queue (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) and process the bulk of the work in there.

Your solution should work fine if placed at the beginning of the controller. I might be being thick, but you want to reject ones where the hash matches, so you need to remove the !

i.e.

```
if(hash_equals($request->session()->get('custom_token'), $request->custom_token)){
    flash()->error('Order placed twice');
    return redirect('/checkout/thank-you');
}

$request->session()->put('custom_token', Str::random(40));
```

I assume you are creating your hash, storing it and passing it to you Form and it is being returned correctly to your controller in the $request? Try setting the custom_token to something like 'fred_bloggs' and just make sure it is coming in correctly.

Comment: Sorry the code is not very clear with the thank you redirect. Actually if that first condition is true it means the script has been duplicate requested.  Therefore if the hash is not the same we should not run the rest of the script.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use transaction with a try catch like this in controller code:

```
try{
   \DB::beginTransaction(); //initiate the transaction and lock the database or table
   //execute your desired code here

   \DB::commit(); //commit the changes and unlock the database or table
}catch(\Exception $e){
   \DB::rollback(); //revert to original state if something goes wrong
}
```

Comment: I presume it's about the same form data being submitted twice rather than one DB insertion interfering with another.(Didn't downvote)

Comment: Yes that's correct, same form data being sent twice.

Comment: Could you disable the submit button before submit with an ajax request

Comment: We can (and do) but need a reliable back end protection too.